# AWS Unexpected SQS Usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am new to AWS, so I was just practicing with few services and right now I am working on the SQS Service. Even though I only did few requests but after 2 3 days I am seeing an unexpected spike.
[image]

How is this even possible? or is there a bug in the aws logs? or is this kind of common thing?

But I know I only did few requests (3-5) and then didn't do any. So why is my Current Usage so high?

Comment: Did  you delete the queues you've created? Did you check all regions that you've used?

Comment: did you stop your services?  Did you code your services so they do not retry failed deliveries indefinitely?  Are you deleting SQS messages once they have been processed?

Comment: @Marcin the queue was not deleted, but now I have deleted it.

Comment: @mcfinnigan yes I am doing it I am returning Task.Completed (so I think it is automatically deleted) the code is in C#

Comment: Given that they are all the same quantity, it is probably the SQS management console accessing the queues when listing them in the console. For example, to show how many messages are in the queue.